# how to implement captive portal

Tags: networking, routes

Hello I am trying to set up a captive portal for my home, but I have a problem and hope someone could help. This is how it looks :
[network schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US0VZ.png)
 I have setup the server to share internet connection and it is working fine. On the on server I can not get the real source of request, and I need it to allow or redirect the request. I have not done this can of thing before. Can someone please help me do solve this ?